# Cakephp 3.0, get id from URL when using on IFrame

Tags: php, iframe, get, query-string, cakephp-3.0

I am using `CakePHP` project in `IFrame`. I have a query string `bid` in the URL.(Eg: `http://localhost:8765/?bid=Mjc`). Initially I use `$_GET['bid']`. Later I have used `$this->request->query['bid']`.

The last method I used is working fine when I call the URL directly into the browser. But when I call the URL from `IFrame`(Eg: `<iframe src='http://localhost:8765/?bid=Mjc' id='WidgetFrame'>`), the `$this->request->query` array comes empty.

Could any one please suggest me best method to get `bid` from URL.

NOTE: Using `$_GET['bid']` working on both `Browser` and `IFrame`.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you can supply something reproducable, I'd doubt that this problem really exists in that form generally, because when `$_GET` is available, then its data will also be accessible via the request object, as it is being fed from `$_GET` by default. Here's a working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/ov23q488/**, the query string value is being picked up just fine. You'll have to do some debugging to figure where exactly the data is being lost, then check back with the results, and maybe someone will be able to help you with this.

Comment: Do supply more code in your question and we can help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$this->request->query('bid')` instead of `$this->request->query['bid']`?